# Using timeout with non-IO function haskell

Tags: haskell

I have function `fun1` that is not IO and can be computationally expensive, so I want to run it for a specified amount of seconds max. I found a function `timeout`, but it requires this `fun1` to be of `IO`.

```
timeout :: Int -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
```

How can I circumvent this, or is there a better approach to achieve my goal?

Edit:
I revised first sentence `fun1` is NOT `IO`, it is of type `fun1 :: Formula -> Bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close to what `talex` said except moving the `seq` should work.  Here is an example using inefficient `fib` as the expensive computation.

```
Prelude> import System.Timeout
Prelude System.Timeout> :{
Prelude System.Timeout| let fib 0 = 0
Prelude System.Timeout|     fib 1 = 1
Prelude System.Timeout|     fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
Prelude System.Timeout| :}
Prelude System.Timeout> timeout 1000000 (let x = fib 44 in x `seq` return x)
Nothing
Prelude System.Timeout>
```

Comment: [`evaluate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate) has better exceptional behavior than ```x `seq` return x```.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting function execution to a specific time length is not pure (i.e. it does not ensure the same result every time), hence you should not be pursuing such behavior outside of `IO`. You can, for example, use something *evil* like `unsafePerformIO (timeout 1000 (pure fun1))` but such usage will quickly lead to programs that are hard to understand with unexpected quirks. A better idea may be to define a custom monad that allows limited time execution and can be lifted to `IO` but I don't know if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
import System.Timeout (timeout)
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Control.DeepSeq (NFData, force)

timeoutPure :: Int -> a -> IO (Maybe a)
timeoutPure t = timeout t . evaluate

timeoutPureDeep :: NFData a => Int -> a -> IO (Maybe a)
timeoutPureDeep t = timeoutPure t . force
```

You may not want to actually write these functions, but they demonstrate the right approach. `evaluate` is better than `seq` for this sort of thing, because `seq` can potentially be moved around by the compiler, escaping the `timeout`. I'm not sure if that's actually possible in this case, but it's better to just do the thing that's sure to work than to try to analyze carefully whether the riskier approach is okay.